# What is the meaning of to have in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Quite frankly, to have the ACLU even make that insinuation is not only insulting, it's completely misinformed

How can change this sentence into a simple sentence? What denotes 'to have' in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

To have someone do something *normally* means to ask or order someone to do something for you, depending on whether your relationship is one in which you can issue orders or one in which you can only ask. You can have a look at [this webpage](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/have_1) and to scroll down to #25.

However, in this particular sentence, it's not used in this meaning. It means simply "the fact that ACLU made this insinuation"—and we now have this fact on our hands, so to say. This sentence is a bit disjointed in other senses, too. E. g., the speaker means that ACLU is misinformed, but the structure of the sentence implies that "the fact that..." is misinformed. A fact can't be misinformed. It's only someone or someone's opinion that can be misinformed. If someone had written this sentence for a book, an editor would have changed this into something like "The fact that ACLU made this statement shows ACLU to be completely misinformed."

So do not take this sentence as an example of good syntax. It's not. It's obviously spoken English where the speaker isn't making an effort to be completely syntactically correct.

Comment: Good response. The syntax is a bit clumsy. But it may have helped to have provided a full alternative.  Though "to have" is idiomatic in this context it is unneccessary. I would have said: *The ACLU's making that suggestion. is not only insulting - but they are completely misinformed.*